# How to check root partition with fsck?

Tags: boot, linux-mint, root, fsck

I installed Linux Mint 12 KDE, and I would like to check the root partition for any errors.

How do I check the root partition with fsck at boot time?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
```

Then reboot.

Comment: This works, but for whatever reason, systemd recommends to pass `fsck.mode=force` on the kernel command line instead. (A warning appears in `journalctl -xb`.)

Comment: Did it for me (Debian 10).

Comment: @SeppoEnarvi: the `forcefsck` is (was?) natively supported only by system V init, but neither upstart nor systemd. The support for it may be added by the distro (Debian and, therefore, Ubuntu, do). The solution you mention is distro-independent. Too bad it's not a simple business to pass anything on the kernel command line on a headless server or a cloud VM...

Comment: This no longer works, fsck.mode=force is now required. https://askubuntu.com/a/1352782/293072

Answer (score 29):

You can use shutdown command for this too.

```
shutdown -rF now
```

From man:

> The  -F  flag means 'force fsck'.
>   This only creates an advisory file /forcefsck which can be tested by the system when it comes up again. The boot rc file can test if this file is present, and decide to run fsck(1) with a special `force' flag so that even properly unmounted file systems get checked. After that, the boot process should remove /forcefsck.

Comment: I tried this with Linux Mint 15 MATE and it didn't cause a check when rebooting.  But `sudo touch /forcefsck` worked when I did that before `sudo reboot`.

Comment: `shutdown` supplied with Upstart does not support the `-F` option any more. You should use `sudo touch /forcefsck` instead. See for example [Why was -F removed from /sbin/shutdown?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64131/19702) and [Bug #74139: shutdown missing -F (force fsck) option](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/74139).

Comment: is linux mint 12, should work

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way to do this:

`tune2fs -C 2 -c 1 /dev/THEDEVTHATROOTIS`

reboot

then the filesystem will be checked, and once all is good you should do

`tune2fs -c 60 /dev/THEDEVTHATROOTIS`

I have assumed that the max-mount-count was set to 60, you should find out before issuing the first command with

`dumpe2fs /dev/THEDEVTHATROOTIS |grep "Maximum mount count"`

Comment: your answer is good and ... should work most of the time (I mean on most of standard installed Linux) BUT, you ASSUME that root partition is ext2,3,4 formatted, what if is something else like xfs or reiserfs ? :)

Comment: True this is a 9/10 solution.

Answer (score 3):

On my systems (several x86 notebooks and a Banana Pi Pro), saying `sudo shutdown now` brings me to runlevel 1 (aka maintenance mode) where I can safely check my root FS:

```
mount -o remount,ro /dev/rootpartition
fsck /dev/rootpartition
reboot
```

There's no need to alter `/etc/fstab` to do this, and I have the opportunity to run `fsck` with whatever options that may be needed to fix a tricky case.

Note: `/forcefsck` and `tune2fs` tricks work on x86, but not on Banana Pi.

Comment: It would be possible to make `tune2fs` etc work on any platform, given that a (possibly embedded) initramfs is supported. So it really just depends on the Linux distribution.

Comment: Answer not working for remote checkings.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Yeah, you need access to a local terminal in single user mode, hence the name.

Answer (score 0):

On modern linux systems the answers above (with forcefsck) don’t work. You have to do it manually:

1. Put your root partition into **read-only mode** by modifying the faulty partition’s line on `/etc/fstab` (but remember your old settings):

   ```
   UUID=fd1d0fad-3a4c-457f-9b5e-eed021cce3d1 /                       ext4    remount,ro        1 1
   ```
2. Reboot
3. Switch to runlevel 1 just to minimize the amount of interfering processes:

   ```
   init 1
   ```
4. Fix your file system (replace /dev/sda2 with your partition’s device), which should now work because the root partition is in read only:

   ```
   fsck /dev/sda2
   ```
5. Reboot. (On my Fedora 21 system I had to [change to runlevel 1 during boot with Grub2](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-change-boot-runlevel-with-grub2/), because otherwise the system was stuck due to not being able to write on the root-partition)
6. Make your root file system readable/writable:

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda2
   ```
7. Restore your /etc/fstab to its original state.
8. Reboot

---

Source: http://bitsofmymind.com/2014/03/14/how-to-fix-fsck-your-root-file-system-that-you-have-to-boot-into-on-linux/

Comment: Could you please elaborate on these “modern Linux systems”, that are, in keeping with the question, Linux Mint?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Raspberry pi and you find yourself in emergency mode, you can in fact unmount the root partition and still use fsck

```
(login as root)
mount -o remount,ro /
fsck
reboot
```

Comment: mount point is busy, ubuntu20